# How to add zooming functionality in PrintManager in android?

Tags: android

I want to add zooming functionality in `PrintManager` in android.Below is my code and sample image.

```
private void createWebPrintJob(WebView webView) {
       PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
    String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
    PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = webView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(jobName);
    PrintJob printJob = printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter,
            new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
    printJobs.add(printJob);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you cannot add anything to this view.

All the print display and settings are handle by the Print Service as you can see from `PRINT_SERVICE` in `PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);`

You can only suggest a limited number of settings to the `PRINT_SERVICE` via the `PrintAttributes`

Comment: But some app has zooming functionality in printing layout.

Comment: I've not seen any Apps do this, not even Google's own Apps have the functionality, or other major apps BUT I'm sure it is possible for an App to not use they builtin print service and methods and write their own to talk to printers directly and thus be able to offer zooming.